# mysql_query returns true when executing joined UPDATE query

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am creating a script in `PHP` that updates my users, user_personal and user_extra table in `MySQL` using joins. When i execute the query using `mysql_query` it returns true, but the tables are not updated.

I've read online that `mysql_query` return false if it fails or a `MySQL` resource if it succeeds, and also read that this is a known bug by `PHP`.

This is the query in question.

```
UPDATE users
        INNER JOIN user_personal
        ON users.id = user_personal.id
        INNER JOIN user_extra
        ON users.id = user_extra.id
        SET
        users.email                      = '" . $user->email . "',              
        user_extra.life_condition        = '" . $user->life_condition . "',
        user_extra.keycode               = '" . $user->keycode . "',
        user_extra.contact_person_phone  = '" . $user->contact_person_phone . "',
        user_extra.doctor                = '" . $user->doctor . "',
        user_extra.doctor_phone          = '" . $user->doctor_phone . "',
        user_extra.doctorpost_phone      = '" . $user->doctorpost_phone . "',
        user_extra.condition             = '" . $user->condition . "',
        user_extra.allergy               = '" . $user->allergy . "',
        user_extra.goal                  = '" . $user->goal . "',
        user_extra.attention_officer     = '" . $user->attention_officer . "',
        user_extra.primary_respon        = '" . $user->primary_respon . "',
        user_personal.name               = '" . $user->name . "',
        user_personal.last_name          = '" . $user->last_name . "',
        user_personal.insertion          = '" . $user->insertion . "',
        user_personal.birthdate          = '" . $user->birthdate . "',
        user_personal.sex                = '" . $user->sex . "',
        user_personal.street_name        = '" . $user->street_name . "',
        user_personal.house_number       = '" . $user->house_number . "',
        user_personal.postal_code        = '" . $user->postal_code . "',
        user_personal.city               = '" . $user->city . "',
        user_personal.country            = '" . $user->country . "',
        user_personal.tel_nr             = '" . $user->tel_nr . "',
        user_personal.contact_person     = '" . $user->contact_person . "'
        WHERE user_personal.name         = '" . $user->name . "'
```

When I executed a smaller test version of the query using one `INNER JOIN` the function returned a resource, same results when i do the query without joins.
My server uses `PHP` 5.3.3 and `Apache` version 2.2.15 with MySQL server 5.1.69.

Can you explain how this happens? And is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Did you remember to commit the transaction?

Comment: Its not an transaction sql, just an normal query.

Comment: check `mysql_affected_rows()` should be 0 meaning your update statement didn't match any rows.

Comment: if `WHERE user_personal.name = '" . $user->name . "'` is not exist then also it will return true.

Comment: yes, i just read the documentation on php.net and read the same, stupid i didn't think of that. I will use mysql_affected_rows() to check if the query has succeeded and recheck my query. Thanks for the comments guys.

Comment: A successful query can still affect/return 0 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read the documentation on PHP.net and learned when using INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP the method returns true or false

When using SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN you get an resource when the query is successful and false when the query failed.

Thanks for the comments guys.